# Find the number of real values of $x$ such that $x^2 + 10000[x] = 10000x$ ($[]$ is the floor function)

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the number of real values of $x$ such that $x^2 + 10000[x] = 10000x$ ($[]$ is the floor function)

**What I Tried**: If $x$ is an integer then :-
$$x^2 = 0$$
$$\rightarrow x = 0$$
So $x = 0$ is the only integer solution, the problem with me is to look for real solutions. I have no clear idea on how to start doing it. One thing I did was let $[x] = x - \{x\}$ . We have :-
$$x^2 + 10000(x - \{x\}) = 10000x$$
$$\rightarrow x^2 - 10000\{x\} = 0$$
$$\rightarrow x^2 = 10000\{x\}$$
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: When considering the RHS $10000\{x\}$ as a scaled sawtooth wave, the LHS parabola should cross each tooth in $[n, n+1)$ once for $n = -100, -99, \ldots, 99$.

Comment: Can this be solved with only algebra? without geometry?

Comment: This would translate to: for each tooth for $n=-100, -99, \ldots, 99$, $10000\{n\} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to (n+1)^-}10000\{x\} = 10000$, and $0\le x^2\le 10000$ for $x\in [-100, 100]$, so by intermediate value theorem there's one root per each listed $n$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know calculus, I am an 8th grader. Can any easy solutions be found?

Comment: Do you know how to solve second degree equations?

Comment: @Oussema definitely, but how will it help here? Please explain.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I can develop the idea in a bit. In short, you use x = [x] + {x} and make a second degree equation in {x} with [x] as a parameter. And you calculate the discriminant and find the roots as a function of [x].

Comment: Ok, it will be great if you post an answer then.

Comment: Someone did it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

$$x = n + r, \; n \in \mathbb{Z}, \; 0 \le r \lt 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Your equation then becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x^2 + 10000\lfloor x\rfloor & = 10000x \\
(n + r)^2 + 10000n & = 10000(n + r) \\
n^2 + 2nr + r^2 - 10000r & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Treat the above equation as a quadratic in $n$ and use the quadratic formula to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n & = \frac{-2r \pm \sqrt{(2r)^2 - 4(r^2 - 10000r)}}{2} \\
& = \frac{-2r \pm \sqrt{40000r}}{2} \\
& = -r \pm 100\sqrt{r}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note $-r - 100\sqrt{r}$ is a strictly decreasing function, going from $0$ down to just greater than $-1 - 100 = -101$, i.e., $(-101, 0]$, so the integer values are $-100 \le n \le 0$. With $-r + 100\sqrt{r}$, it's a strictly increasing function, going from $0$ to just less than $-1 + 100 = 99$, i.e., $[0, 99)$, so the integer values are $0 \le n \le 98$. Altogether, the integer values are $-100 \le n \le 98$, with just one value of $r$ for each integer $n$, giving a total of $199$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's has 398 solutions
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{10000}\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{10000}{x} \\ $$
$${x}^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{10000}\left\{{x}\right\}=\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{10000}\right) \\ $$
$${x}=\left(-\mathrm{100};\mathrm{100}\right) \\ $$
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\left[-\mathrm{99};\mathrm{99}\right] \\ $$
$$\left({x}−\mathrm{5000}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{5000}^{\mathrm{2}} −\mathrm{10000}\lfloor{x}\rfloor \\ $$
$${x}=\mathrm{100}\left(\mathrm{50}\pm\sqrt{\mathrm{2500}−\left[-\mathrm{99};\mathrm{99}\right]}\right) \\ $$